# Issue when creating a new Plone site

Tags: plone, zodb, plone-4.x

After installing plone.reload product i am facing this issue ,when creating a new site :

```
 (<InterfaceClass plone.app.viewletmanager.interfaces.IViewletSettingsStorage>, '')
```

Comment: Any chance you're using the id "plone" (all lower case) when creating or viewing for your site?

Comment: no i did't do that..StaveM

Comment: i can remember that i had issues when using sauna.reload for packages that depend on other packages that do not have z3c.autoinclude support. their zcml is not loaded an you get lookup errors.

Comment: please add your complete traceback to the question

Comment: i am using plone.reload egg for reloading the site but after using that i was facing the issue and after remove that its work successfully  fRiSi